# Display all surveys using content query web part

Tags: sharepoint, survey, cqwp

I am new to sharepoint development. I have created a subsite and called it Surveys. This will contain all the surveys created in the portal. Now, I want to display the latest survey on the homepage. I though I would be able to do that using a content query web part, sort the CQWP descendently on survey creation date and restrict the number of displayed items to one.

Unfortunately, this doesnt work at all! Is my solution achievable? It seems to me that the Survey content types isn't a normal one as I can't see it in the content types gallery. How could my requirement be fulfilled (without code)?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

OOTB Survey List does not contain any [Content Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.aspx) and it has the following structure:

- Response entry is represented by [List Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- Response entry consist of questions and answers, where Question correspond to [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.aspx) and Answer to Item value respectively.

---

For querying Survey List via CQWP  the following properties could be used

- [BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.basetype.aspx)  `<Lists BaseType="4">`
- [ServerTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.servertemplate.aspx) `<Lists ServerTemplate="102">`

### Example

To retrieve all the responses from Survey lists, specify **List Type** property as shown on picture

[image]